# Unable to access private variable declared on a class from a call back function

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In my data service , I am trying to display error using toastr, on an exception.

To do that I am creating a class, loading the API , on success return data , else handle the exception.

```
export class DataService {

  private productUrl = "api/Products11";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  public products: Product[] = [];

  loadProducts(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.productUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((data: any[]) => {
          this.products = data;
          return true;
      }), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    //this.toastr is undefined here
     this.toastr.success(errorMessage);
  }

}
```

But, When I set a break point on handleError , I am getting `this.toastr` as undefined. Same, if I am trying to access `this.productUrl` .

Everything works fine on loadProducts method.

Comment: Hi, check if you are importing ToastrService properly

Comment: Service is injected properly.It works as expected on loadProducts, but not on handleError

Comment: Asked a million times already. Replace `catchError(this.handleError))`by `catchError(e => this.handleError(e)))`

Comment: @JBNizet, This fixed. Quick google did not show up. Can understand your concern. Thanks !